# Bootstrap modal turns the page into an empty canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

My bootstrap modal is working when using `data-toggle="modal" data-target="chart"` But when I open a modal using javascript `.modal()` it turns the page into all white.

HTML:

```
    <div id="myModal">
        <div class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
      </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var base = $('#myModal');
    base.modal();
    //i even tried base.modal("show")
```

Comment: I think you want to add the `id="myModal"` to the `div` with the `modal` class on it. Then try `$("#myModal").modal("show");`

Comment: I did and it worked, thanks. Why is this not on this documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ ??

Comment: yes ofcourse it is in the bootstrap documentation, sorry. It's on Usage > Via Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id attribute `myModal` has to be placed into your `<div class="modal">` element.

The following code could work :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
</script>
```